# After Upgrade to 12.04 - cannot connect to network

Tags: 12.04

Upgraded this morning and the install seemed to go well but after reboot I logged back in and it appears that my network (wired) set up no longer works.

I've tried restarting the network manager but no joy there.

Any tips on how I can get this resolved???

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm also having the same experience. Wired or wireless interface, neither sees the network. The wireless network connects to the access point, and I get a valid DHCP IP address, netmask, gateway, etc. Seems like this might be an issue with the iptables/ipchains config, but I'm not comfortable editting the tables by hand.

Comment: OK.  I was wrong about the wired interface.  That gets out, but the wireless does not, at least not after getting the address info from the DHCP server on the net.  And it doesn't appear to be a firewall issue, as I turned it off and still no packets going out the wireless interface.  I'm installed on a Dell Latitude E6500.  Ubuntu 11.10 was working just fine on it, with either wired or wireless interface.  Maybe this can point someone else at a solution?

Comment: VTC as not reproducible because this is 12.04 which is EOL. Plus OP hasn't signed on since Nov 2015 and cannot reply to comments on problem progress.