# Network/browser issues after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I let my laptop upgrade to 12.04. And have no network afterwards. 
I went through all the articles I could find in google.

Right now, I can ping google, and yahoo, but not cnn.com for example or anything else.
Firefox says it can't reach google.com or gmail.com (or anything, not even IP.

> /etc/network/interfaces

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8                       <<<<<added
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

> /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;                 <<<<< tried both
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` with and without *dns=dnsmasq* commented out.

I can ping my wireless router and connect to it just fine.

Have tried proxy/noproxy.

This looks like [After Upgrade to 12.04 - cannot connect to network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126052/after-upgrade-to-12-04-cannot-connect-to-network)  but no answer there.

I would hate to do a fresh install. 
Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. No more cable network after upgrade !!! The only solution I found is to remove the network manager and manually edit my /etc/network/interfaces file to have network using cable working;

Unfortunately, this solution has the drawback than nothing is display in notification area.

For information, a fresh install didn't solve the issue for me, so I guess there is some bug somewhere with the network manager.

to remove network-manager

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

A reboot may be required ...

edit the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the following lines depending on the network connexion you want to use (eth0, th1, etc ...)

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: How do you remove the network manager?

Comment: I edited the answer to answer.

Comment: I tried the interfaces modification, after that reboot I could not use nm-tool. Removed the eth1 entry (which happens to be my wireless), rebooted and still says connect: Network is unreachable. Seriously, a OS update should not leave you in a mess like this.

Comment: So, I am back to a stage where I can ping all sorts of websites. but browsers still don't work. I do not have firestarter, so no idea why my connections get refused.